# Socket.IO receive callback value

Tags: android, sockets, socket.io

Is it possible to receive a value or listen an event on a client from a server without the server emitting?

if the server only has

```
socket.on('get_name', function(data, callback) {

try {
    var name = nameService.getNameById(data.refId);
    if (!name) return callback({error:true,code:801,message:'Name does not exist!'});
    callback(name.format());
  } catch (err) {
     callback({error:true,code:999,message:err.message});
  }
}
```

how can I return the data back to the client? As you can see, it doesnt have any emit so client cannot listen via event?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, check this link: [AndroidAsync Socket.IO receive callback value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24137412/androidasync-socket-io-receive-callback-value/24157316#24157316). Basically consists on using emitEvent method.