# AndroidAsync Socket.IO receive callback value

Tags: android, node.js, callback, socket.io

I'm trying to build an application for Android using this library: https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync and I was trying to receive a callback value from the server like this but the app crashes:

> ```
>   client.emit("callbackTry", new Acknowledge() {
>         @Override
>         public void acknowledge(JSONArray arg0) {
>             Log.e(TAG,"acknowledge: "+ arg0);
>         }
>   });
> ```

I leave you the server-side:

> ```
> socket.on('callbackTry', function (callback) {
>     console.log(callback);
>     var hello = "Hello";
>     callback(hello);
> });
> ```

How can I return the data back to the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself which consists on changing emit method to emitEvent. Hope it really help someone else too.